# JBOSS fuse proxying the schema

Tags: xsd, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I tried to create router with JBoss Fuse/Camel and deployed in successfully.

```
<camelContext id="blueprintContext"
                trace="false"
                xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="httpBridge">
      <from uri="jetty:http://mysystem:8282/CreateAccountService?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
      <to uri="jetty:http://mysystem:8080/service/services/CreateAccountService?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
    </route>
  </camelContext>
```

Able to access the service using proxy.

I have used xsd for data types in wsdl.

```
<wsdl:types>
<xsd:schema xmlns:fault="http://www.sample.project.com.au/common/message/FaultMessage/v1" xmlns:pref="http://www.sample.project.com.au/services/account/CreateAccount/CreateAccountRequest/v1" xmlns:pref1="http://www.sample.project.com.au/services/account/CreateAccount/CreateAccountResponse/v1" xmlns:pref2="http://www.sample.project.com.au/common/message/TechnicalException/v1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tns="http://www.sample.project.com.au/services/account/CreateAccount/v1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" targetNamespace="http://www.sample.project.com.au/services/account/CreateAccount/v1">
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.sample.project.com.au/services/account/CreateAccount/CreateAccountRequest/v1" schemaLocation="http://mysystem:8080/service/services/CreateAccountService?xsd=CreateAccountRequest.xsd"></xsd:import>
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.sample.project.com.au/services/account/CreateAccount/CreateAccountResponse/v1" schemaLocation="http://mysystem:8080/service/services/CreateAccountService?xsd=CreateAccountResponse.xsd"></xsd:import>
</xsd:schema>
</wsdl:types>
```

`http://mysystem:8282/CreateAccountService?wsdl` (Proxy)

But, I can see all the xsd details in wsdl with

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://www.sample.project.com.au/services/account/CreateAccount/CreateAccountRequest/v1" schemaLocation="http://mysystem:8080/service/services/CreateAccountService?xsd=CreateAccountRequest.xsd"></xsd:import>
```

which is original url of the schema.

```
http://mysystem:8080/service/services/CreateAccountService?xsd=CreateAccountRequest.xsd
```

I want to hide this details also.

But, I was able to see all the schema with actual url details.

How can I create the proxy for all the contents in the URI.

If I am not clear with my question, please let me know.

Comment: @clause ibsen, please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)

You need to process the reply message (using message translator eip  http://camel.apache.org/message-translator.html) before returning it to the client, so you can replace the url in the message body from the actual url, to the proxy url

For example you can use a bean with a single method that does the search/replace

```
public String transformTheMessage(String body) {
  ...
  ... search for the url you want to replace
}
```

And then define a bean in the xml file and use it in the Camel route

```
<route id="httpBridge">
      <from uri="jetty:http://mysystem:8282/CreateAccountService?matchOnUriPrefix=true"/>
      <to uri="jetty:http://mysystem:8080/service/services/CreateAccountService?bridgeEndpoint=true&amp;throwExceptionOnFailure=false"/>
      <to uri="bean:myBean"/>
    </route>
```

2)

Or check if the request is for the WSDL and do a content based router, and return the content from a file which you have on the proxy server - and the file has the proxy urls hardcoded etc.
http://camel.apache.org/content-based-router.html

3)

Or check out this example

- https://camel.apache.org/cxf-proxy-example.html

Comment: I tried the bean solution and its works great and I tried to get the Exchange inside the bean, it says null, what is the problem??  But, I will suggest the second option. I haven't tried though.